# Sent messages labeling issue

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have one Gmail account made last year that has a `Sent Messages` label and another Gmail account without it.

I think this was Gmail's default, but for some reason it was erased on the newer account, or Gmail stopped having that label somewhere. I tried finding the logic / rules for it, but there's nothing I can uncover to mimic it.

Does anyone know the formula for it?

I don't want it to label messages that are replies in my Inbox, just the ones in Sent.

[image: Sent Messages label on my old account]
[image: after clicking edit]

I've looked through a few answers, and came up that I need the is:sent rule, but I don't know how to incorporate advanced parameters into a label filter.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is to apply the `is:sent` rule, then you need to do this via *Filters*, not *Labels*

Go to `Settings` > `Filters` > `Create a new filter`

You can set up a filter in the "From" field to say `from:me`

You would then "Continue" and "Apply the label: < your label>" - This should allow you to create a Sent label for all messages from you.

Not sure what the larger problem of losing your default label is though.